# Linuxのインストール時にM.2 SSDが認識されない

Tags: linux

Linuxをインストールしようとしたのですが、m.2のSSDを使用しているみたいで、LinuxでSSDを認識しません。何か解決策はありますでしょうか。
機種はXPS 13 プラチナです。

Comment: [PCIe M2ドライブを搭載したシステム上でのUbuntuのロード](https://www.dell.com/support/article/jp/ja/jpbsd1/sln299303/pcie-m2%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%82%92%E6%90%AD%E8%BC%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AEubuntu%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89?lang=ja)

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事インストールできました。

Answer (score 1):

@sayuri 氏のコメントにより、この質問は解決したようです。外部サイトにある内容ですが、引用して回答としておきます。（一部画像が表示されないなどありますが、英語版に変更することで正常に表示されました。 -- 2019/05/01時点）

> #### ハード ドライブが認識されない
>
> PCIeベースのm2ドライブしかないシステムでUbuntu 14.04/15.04メディアを起動すると、インストーラがハード ドライブを検出できないことがあります（通常、インストーラはデフォルトで/dev/sdxのみを検索します）。
>
> #### NVMEロード
>
> メモ: ユーザーはシステムBIOS（起動時にF2キー）にアクセスし、SATA設定をAHCIに変更する必要があります。この変更後もドライブが認識されない場合。ユーザーは、次の手順に従ってください。
>
> - 起動時に次のカーネル引数を追加します。
>     `nvme_load=YES`
> - キーボード プロンプトが表示されたら、F12を押します。
> - Enterキーを押して言語を選択します。を押します。
> - Escキーを押します。
> - ブート オプションを変更して「nvme_load=yes」を追加し、「quiet splash ---」を削除します。
> - Enterキーを押します。
> - インストーラで利用可能なNVMEドライブが表示されます。
>     コントローラー:    Nvme0
>     ポート:             N1
>     パーティション:       Px
>
> [PCIe M2ドライブを使用したUbuntuのシステムへのロード | Dell 日本](https://www.dell.com/support/article/jp/ja/jpdhs1/sln299303/pcie-m2%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fubuntu%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89?lang=ja)

Comment: この回答は次のメタ質問を参考にコミュニティWikiとして投稿したものです。 [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1812/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e6%b8%88%e3%81%bf%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e4%ba%8b%e5%be%8c%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86)