# ElementaryOS(Ubuntuベース)のインストールができません…

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

初めて質問します。
知識が足りずどうしても自分で解決できないので教えていただきたいです。

■やりたいこと
Windows10homeが入っているノートPC(Lenovo ideaPad C340)に[ElementaryOS](https://elementary.io/ja/)というUbuntuベースのOSをインストールしたいです。
Windowsが好きじゃないので飛ばしてもいいのですが、容量が余っているのでとりあえずデュアルブートにしようとしています。

■問題
LiveUSBを作成した後tryモードでは動くのですが、インストール時に選択できるパーティションが無くインストールができません。
ターミナルでファイルシステムを確認すると、インストーラを入れたUSB(32GB)しか認識していませんでした。
おそらくLinux領域用にパーティションを切ってやったりしないといけないと思うのですが、上手くできません。(というかそこまで知識がないです)
一応エンジニアなので基本的なことはわかっているつもりですが、パーティションとかext4とかなると　んーーって感じです。
ただ、どうしてもこのOSを入れたいので解決したいです。
よろしくお願いします。

■やったこと
1.ElementaryOSのインストーラー(isoファイル)を公式からダウンロード
2.Rufusを使ってLiveUSBを作成
　→isoのハッシュが問題ないこと確認済み
　→パーティション構成：GPT
　→ターゲットシステム：UEFI(GPTにした時点で固定)
3.SSDのディスク管理
　→512GBのSSDをCドライブ(とシステム標準)が独占していたので最小限確保したまま、
　 残りを開放
3.BIOSでSecureBOOTをOFF
4.BOOTMODEをUSB優先に変更
5.tryモードで起動→正常に動作
6.インストール→できない

■補足
他の方の記事にあるようなパーティション選択画面の前に、デュアルブートにするかどうかなどを選択する画面はできませんでした。
またパーティション選択画面にて＋ボタンを押すと、インストーラーがクラッシュしました　というエラーが出ます。

[image: 問題のパーティション選択画面]

Comment: まずSSDを認識しているのかを確認する必要があると思います。LiveUSBの環境から `sudo parted | grep dev` とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。記載が漏れておりましたが「parted print」コマンドを実行してもUSB(32GB)しか出力されておらず、SSDは認識していないと思われます。このSSDを認識させるためにLinux用のパーティションを切ったりしないといけないのかな？とか思っているのですが、理解ができていません；　grep devをしてもpartedは対話モードになるので、/dev/sdaと出力されるだけです。

Comment: すみません、オプション無しだと仰るとおり対話モードになってしまいますね。`sudo parted -l | grep dev` になります。パーティションを切るにはまずデバイスとして認識していないといけません。

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございます。上記のコマンドを実行してみましたが、やはり/dev/sda:32GBしか表示されませんでした。。　どうすればSSDを認識するようにできるのでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみに、BIOSはきちんとSSDを認識しており製品名も記載されています。

Comment: ハード構成を考えると、過去質問(の回答)が参考になるかもしれません。 - [Linuxのインストール時にM.2 SSDが認識されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49003)

Comment: ありがとうございます。色々試してみたいと思います。