# HP 250 G8 notebookにubuntu 16.04が入らない

Tags: linux, ubuntu

HP 250 G8 notebookにubuntu 16.04をインストールできません。
rufusでブートデバイスUSBを作り,インストーラーを起動させたのですがインストールする記憶域を認識
していないのか(画像参照)インストールできませんでした。試しにubuntu 22.04をインストールしてみましたがこちらは問題なくインストールできました。
どのような対処法がありますか？
PC: HP250 G8 notebook
SSD:SAMSUNG MZNLH128HBHQ-000H1

[image: 記憶域を認識しない]

Comment: あえて古い OS バージョンを選択している理由はなぜですか？ OS が古ければそれだけ最新のハードには対応していない可能性が出てきます。

Comment: 重複候補: [Linuxのインストール時にM.2 SSDが認識されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49003/3060)

Comment: この画面で「Install Now」を押すとどうなるのでしょうか。